# Laravel's links inside JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have link in my js:

```
 url: '/admin/products/ajax-remove-image/' + $('a.myimg').data('name'),
```

But after git clone from repositories this link not working because I must use like as:

```
url: '/public/admin/products/ajax-remove-image/' + $('a.myimg').data('name'),
```

How to make this dynamic ? I think this one:

```
  url: '{{url('/admin/products/ajax-remove-image/')}}' + $('a.myimg').data('name'),
```

But this part

```
    $('a.myimg').data('name')
```

is not going together with main link.

Comment: Is it possible you need to add the `/` back in, the one between the path and the `$` part? What does the code look like in the browser?

Comment: it`s work for me ! I just added  ' / '  between url() and $ like:
url: '{{url('/admin/products/ajax-remove-image')}}'+ '/' + $('a.myimg').data('name')

Thx !

Answer (score 1):

You've to configure your virtual host to point on your_project/public directory.
After all, you can use something like that:

```
let url = location.protocol + '//'+ window.location.hostname + '/admin/products/ajax-remove-image/' + $(a.myimg).data('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

put the script on `public/assets` folder  and use `{{ asset('your-filename.ext') }}`